# Invisible object after motion tracking

Tags: rendering

After tracking the camera and adding a scene (invisible plane, camera and light) I used a cube to check my camera track and everything rendered fine. 
I added a rig, but after rendering, the rig appears to share the properties of the plane that makes the shadows happen (the rig is invisible and only shows the shadows of itself).
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you able to upload your blend file?

Comment: An armature doesn't render and doesn't cast shadows, there must be another object doing it. Did you add a mesh for the rig to deform? or is it moving the invisible plane you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the rig is in the right layer, it has to be in the visible render layer